# Custom function applied to dataframe, based on value in id column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I've got a dataframe that contains several columns, including a user ID (id) and a timestamp (startTime). I want to check how many different days my data (df rows) span, per user.

I'm currently doing that by splitting up the df by 'id', and then calculating the following in a loop for each of the subset dfs:

```
days = len(df.startTime.dt.date.unique())
```

How do I do this more efficiently, without splitting up the data frame? I'm working with rather large data frames, and I fear this will take way too much time. I've looked at the groupby function, but I didn't get far. I tried something like:

```
result = df.groupby('id').agg({'days': lambda x: x.startTime.dt.date.unique()})
```

... but that clearly didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can using `drop_duplicates` before `value_counts`

```
df['New Date'] = df['startTime'].dt.date
result = df.drop_duplicates(['ID','New Date']).ID.value_counts()
```

Comment: Well, that already decreased my run time by 60%, so nice! And I tested with a relatively small df, so I expect the gain to be much bigger. Thanks!

Comment: I'm just wondering now: won't adding a column to an otherwise huge df add unnecessary strain om my working memory?

Comment: @Inkidu616 you can change it to int 8 , like `df['New Date']= pd.factorize(df['startTime'].dt.date)[0]`

Comment: Neat! Thanks, didn't know those functions.